# CakePHP populate checkboxes dynamically

Tags: javascript, cakephp, checkbox

currently i am using CakePHP 2.6 and i have 2 tables and a many to many join table:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `iam-test_db`.`accesses` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `location_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `facility_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `department_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `iam-test_db`.`systems` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `facility_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_systems_facilities`
    FOREIGN KEY (`facility_id`)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `iam-test_db`.`accesses_systems` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `access_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `system_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_accesses_systems_accesses`
    FOREIGN KEY (`access_id`)
  CONSTRAINT `fk_accesses_systems_systems`
    FOREIGN KEY (`system_id`)
```

I've created succesfully dependent populating dropdowns for facilities and departments and currently listing all systems as checkboxes in my add form.

My AccessesController.php

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Access->create();
        if ($this->Access->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The access has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The access could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }   
    $locations = $this->Access->Location->find('list');
    $systems = $this->Access->System->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('locations', 'facilities', 'departments', 'systems'));
}
```

And in my accesses/add.ctp i have included this line for checkboxes

```
echo $this->Form->input('System',array(
        'label' => __('Systems',true),
        'id' => 'AccessSystem',
        'div' => 'checkbox',
        'type' => 'select',
        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
        'options' => $systems,
        ));
```

The Location/Facility/Department dropdowns are populate dependent with the JsHelper/jquery.

Now i want the checkboxes also be dependent, from which facility i choose. But atm i have no good idea how to make it. I think i have to use javascript/jquery.

I'm thinking about displaying a button and on click a popup window appears with the facility dependent systems. Is this the right way or do you have any better ideas ??

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your problem, so I am specifying what I thing the problem is. I believe you have many systems and you want to check/uncheck them automatically based on the id of facility. You could create a section for them and include these checkboxes there. The section could have two states, collapsed and expanded and could have a + icon when it is collapsed and a - icon when it is expanded. Clicking the + icon would expand the section and clicking the - icon would collapse the section. Also, you could add a class to the checkboxes. Let's suppose you add a class of `'system-checkbox-' + id`, where `id` is the id of the facility. Also, let's suppose the checkboxes are included into a `div` having the id of `my-section`. Then, checking and unchecking checkboxes depending on the id of facility would happen like this:

```
$("#my-section input:not(.system-checkbox-" + id + ")").prop("checked", false);
$("#my-section input.system-checkbox-" + id).prop("checked", false);
```

Let me know if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I'm sorry u missunderstood my question :p In my accesses/add.ctp form are ALL systems listed unchecked so a user can check the required systems. But i just want to list the systems which belong to the selected facility. I will Update my code examples.

Comment: Then instead of .prop() you can use .hide() and .show(). The same logic, but not with checking and unchecking. You are hiding and showing instead.